# Azure DevOps build With IIS Physical path Failing

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I have an Azure Devops build which tries to build a .NET 4 solution on my build server. The issue is this .NET 4 project doesn't run through IIS Express, but IIS itself, requiring a website with a physical path to be set up.

I'm having trouble figuring out what the physical path would be, as the path changes. One build it could be D:/agent1/s/19/... another build it could be D:/agent1/s/29/...

Has anyone tackled this issue before? I'm finding sparse info on the net.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use this parameter in the build for the folder you want

`/p:OutDir="your folder"` (to plan output)

`/p:PackageLocation="your folder"` (to zip output)

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: xxxx.csproj
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutDir="your folder"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```